# Class "Veins::ObstacleControl" not found

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have followed step by step the tutorial to install Veins, but when I tried running the example scenario (final step) I ended up with the above error.

The whole error was:

> Error in module (cModule) RSUExampleScenario (id=1) during network
>   setup: Class "Veins::ObstacleControl" not found -- perhaps its code
>   was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with
>   Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with
>   Define_Module()/Define_Channel().
>
> TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true
>   configuration option. Is your debugger ready?
>
> Simulation terminated with exit code: -2147483645 Working directory:
>   C:/Users/user/src/veins-4.3/examples/veins Command line:
>   ../../../omnetpp-4.6/bin/opp_run.exe -r 0 -n .;../../src/veins
>   --tkenv-image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini

I don't think I have missed a step during the tutorial as I have tried it two times. I did not make any change in anything, I've just strictly followed the tutorial like a robot, so I cannot provide an MCVE with more details than the tutorial.

Here is what I'm using:
- Windows 7 Pro 64 bits
- SUMO 0.25.0 64 bits

All other steps of the tutorial successfully worked until the final step.

Comment: Can you verify that `out/*/src/veins/modules/obstacle/ObstacleControl.o` is indeed present and has been linked into `libveins.dll`? You can also try running `opp_run -l src/veins -h classes` and see if `Veins::ObstacleControl` appears in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this error occurs when running Veins via the OMNeT++ IDE. Or, if you have compiled it with GCC (The error does not happen if you use CLANG)

There are two ways to bypass this error:

1. Use the `.run` as **executable** from your examples directory, which calls `veins/run` and includes all the required libraries:

[image]

2. Use `opp_run` as **executable** and set **dynamic libraries** to the directory where `libveins.so` is located (usually `src/veins`)

[image]

PS: to answer @ChristopSommer questions: `Veins::ObstacleControl` appears in `opp_run -l src/veins -h classes`

This could be a solution too, but I never tested it: [Compiler flags in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502795/compiler-flags-in-eclipse/19503560#19503560)