# ALSA Lib 1.1.2 Compilation error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, audio, libalsa

I am trying to cross compile ALSA Lib application for linux-arm based processor. I am using eclipse to do the build for me. The build phase of the application is successful but I get errrors when the gcc linker tries to complete.

I get the following errors

> Building target: sound 
>   Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
>   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/proc/asound -L/srv/nfs/rootfs/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/srv/nfs/rootfs/usr/lib -L/srv/nfs/rootfs/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/srv/nfs/rootfs/lib -o "sound"  ./play.o
>   ./play.o: In function `main':
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:13: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_open'
>   makefile:29: recipe for target 'sound' failed
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:14: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:20: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:21: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:26: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:27: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:32: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:33: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:38: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:39: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:44: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:45: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:50: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:51: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:56: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:57: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:62: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_hw_params_free'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:64: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:65: undefined reference to`snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:71: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_writei'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:72: undefined reference to`snd_strerror'
>   /home/neonws/sound/Debug/../play.c:78: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [sound] Error 1

11:15:58 Build Finished (took 75ms)

I am using the [Sample Playback Program](http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html) from ASLA-LIB api.

I am wondering what is causing the linker to fail?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an `asound` library linkage, add `-lasound` to your linking flags (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502795/compiler-flags-in-eclipse) which tells where to do that properly in Eclipse). And probably remove `-L/proc/asound`, I don't think you have your libraries there.

Comment: >Building target: sound
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/home/alsa-lib-1.1.2/include -L/srv/nfs/rootfs/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/srv/nfs/rootfs/usr/lib -L/srv/nfs/rootfs/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/srv/nfs/rootfs/lib -o "sound"  ./play.o   -lasound
/home/gcc-linaro-5.2-2015.11-2-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
makefile:29: recipe for target 'sound' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sound] Error 1

14:18:14 Build Finished (took 76ms)

Comment: Hi @Roman

I followed the directions you suggested and it giving me a linker errors saying "-lasound not found" 

Can you please suggest a solution to this. 

I added "asound" to Libraries(-l) followed by the path in Library search path(-L) for the Linker.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer: it's hard to tell where your libraries are, now you're missing the library in your library search paths, you should add proper path with `-L` parameter. Where do you have your target root file system?