# How do I deal with "undefined reference to `regcomp'" error

Tags: c, eclipse, windows-10, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to Eclipse environment and I'm trying to write a C program in Eclipse installed in Windows 10. Compiler I use is MinGW latest version installed through MSYS2. The program I've written has got regular expressions used in it. When I try to build the code, I get the following errors-

21: undefined reference to `regcomp'
35: undefined reference to`regexec'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZdK4.png)

Can anyone help me resolve this issue??

Comment: It's caused by [Failure to link against appropriate libraries/object files or compile implementation files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1362568)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `#include <regex.h>` in your code and it compiles then it looks like you have the library installed.

But `undefined reference to 'regexec'` is a linker error, which means you're not linking with the library that you are calling functions of.

So you need to link with this library, probably by adding the linker flag `-lregex`.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking these minor details, but I'm new to Eclipse and coding in Windows environment. May I know where'd I get the path for that linker flag? I use MinGW for compilation. So, is there any command to get the path of that -iregex linker flag alone, so that I can add it to my Project in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm don't use Eclipse myself, but this question has been answered before, so if you look for it it 's not that hard to find. Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502795/compiler-flags-in-eclipse